# What is the full list of regions, cities, and their resources?

Tags: simcity-2013

It would be handy to have a web-based list of 'em, when coordinating regions with friends.

What else would you do when you're waiting in queue? :P

Comment: Usually when I'm in the queue I wonder why I purchased the game and expected anything else from EA. Ugh I feel like a beaten spouse that comes back for more and more.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Legend & Notes

**Rail:** Cities with a ✓ have access to railroads.

**Sea:** Cities with a ✓ have access to the waterways & shipping.

**Resources:** Each resource is given a rating based on how dense it is within
the city.  *** indicates that the resource is abundant, no stars indicate that
it is not present.

**City Clusters:** Cities are grouped into their clusters (sub-regions).

- Each city cluster has a great works site.
- Each city cluster is connected via road (you can't trade utilities between clusters)

**Region Maps:** White lines indicate rail, yellow indicates highways.

## Cape Trinity

[image]

[image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Clearwater:            ✓   |   ✓   |       |       |       |   **  |   *
Norwich Hills:         ✓   |       |   **  |   **  |   **  |   **  |   *
Trinity Point:         ✓   |   ✓   |       |       |       |  ***  |   *
```

---

## Whitewater Valley

[image]

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Brakeman's Folley:     ✓   |   ✓   |   **  |  ***  |   *   |   **  |   *
Elm Grove:             ✓   |   ✓   |  ***  |   *   |  ***  |   **  |
Riverbend:             ✓   |   ✓   |   **  |  ***  |   **  |  ***  |
Twain:                 ✓   |   ✓   |       |       |       |  ***  |
Whitewater Crossing:   ✓   |   ✓   |  ***  |   **  |       |   **  |   *
```

---

## Reflection Atoll

[image]

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Grand Haven:           ✓   |   ✓   |       |       |       |  ***  |   *
Ingot Landing:         ✓   |   ✓   |       |  ***  |       |  ***  |   **
Soirée Sands:          ✓   |   ✓   |       |       |       |  ***  |   *
Summit Vista:          ✓   |   ✓   |       |       |       |  ***  |   *
Cinder:                ✓   |   ✓   |  ***  |       |       |   **  |   *
Petrol Bay:            ✓   |   ✓   |       |       |  ***  |  ***  |   *
Trader's Ridge:        ✓   |   ✓   |   *   |   *   |   *   |  ***  |   *
```

---

## Viridian Woods

[image]

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Bamberg Basin:         ✓   |   ✓   |   **  |   *   |   **  |  ***  |   *
Burghausen Hills:      ✓   |       |   *   |  ***  |       |   **  |   *
Hohenburg Shores:          |   ✓   |  ***  |       |  ***  |  ***  |   *
Straussburg Isles:     ✓   |   ✓   |       |       |  ***  |  ***  |   *
```

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Figaro Forest:             |   ✓   |   **  |  ***  |       |  ***  |   *
Giovanni Woods:        ✓   |       |  ***  |   **  |       |  ***  |   *
Tosca Cliffs:              |   ✓   |  ***  |   **  |       |  ***  |   *
Traviata Knoll:        ✓   |       |   **  |  ***  |       |   **  |   *
```

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Gaugin Valley:         ✓   |       |  ***  |   *   |       |  ***  |   *
Matisse Plains:        ✓   |       |  ***  |   **  |       |   **  |   *
Monet Plateau:             |   ✓   |   **  |   **  |   **  |  ***  |   *
Rousseau Flats:        ✓   |       |  ***  |   **  |       |  ***  |   *
```

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Lancaster Pointe:      ✓   |   ✓   |       |   *   |  ***  |  ***  |   *
Tudor Isle:            ✓   |   ✓   |       |       |   **  |  ***  |   *
Wessex Bend:               |   ✓   |   **  |  ***  |   *   |  ***  |   *
Yorkshire Cliffs:      ✓   |       |  ***  |   **  |       |  ***  |   *
```

---

## Sunrunner Bay

[image]

[image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Corsair Coast:             |   ✓   |   *   |   **  |   **  |   **  |   *
Plunder Point:             |   ✓   |   *   |   **  |   *   |   **  |   *
```

---

## Discovery Delta

[image]

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Barleycorn Point:      ✓   |   ✓   |   **  |   **  |       |  ***  |   **
Cotton Bend:           ✓   |   ✓   |   **  |  ***  |       |  ***  |   **
Rising Sun Valley:     ✓   |       |   **  |       |   **  |  ***  |   *
Stackolee Ravine:      ✓   |   ✓   |  ***  |       |   *   |  ***  |   **
```

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Cottonwood Forest:     ✓   |   ✓   |  ***  |  ***  |       |  ***  |   *
Honeysuckle Marsh:     ✓   |   ✓   |   *   |       |   **  |  ***  |   **
Magnolia Wetlands:     ✓   |   ✓   |       |       |       |  ***  |   *
Willow Woods:          ✓   |   ✓   |   **  |  ***  |       |  ***  |   **
```

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Harper Plains:         ✓   |       |  ***  |       |   *   |   *   |   *
Huckleberry Island:    ✓   |   ✓   |  ***  |  ***  |       |  ***  |   *
Sawyer's Crossing:     ✓   |   ✓   |   *   |   **  |       |  ***  |   *
Thatcher Overlook:     ✓   |   ✓   |  ***  |   *   |       |  ***  |   *
```

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Jugband Hills:         ✓   |   ✓   |   **  |   **  |       |  ***  |   **
Kazoo Pass:            ✓   |   ✓   |  ***  |  ***  |       |  ***  |   **
Spooner Plains:            |   ✓   |   *   |       |  ***  |  ***  |   **
Washtub Fields:        ✓   |   ✓   |   *   |       |  ***  |  ***  |   **
```

---

## Horizon Archipelago

[image]

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Ceylon Steppes:        ✓   |   ✓   |   **  |   **  |   **  |  ***  |  ***
Lapsang Landing:       ✓   |   ✓   |   **  |  ***  |       |   **  |   **
Oolong Peak:           ✓   |       |  ***  |   *   |       |   **  |   **
Souchong Summit:       ✓   |   ✓   |  ***  |   *   |       |   **  |   **
```

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Conch Beach:           ✓   |   ✓   |   *   |   **  |   *   |  ***  |   *
Cowrie Cove:           ✓   |   ✓   |  ***  |       |       |   **  |   *
Nautilus Plateau:      ✓   |       |   **  |  ***  |       |  ***  |   **
Triton Valley:         ✓   |       |  ***  |       |       |   **  |  ***
```

[image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Hiroshige Overlook:    ✓   |       |  ***  |       |       |   **  |   **
Hokusai Cliffs:        ✓   |   ✓   |   *   |   **  |   **  |  ***  |  ***
Toyokuni Strand:       ✓   |   ✓   |       |  ***  |  ***  |  ***  |   *
```

---

## Titan Gorge

[image]

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Cedargates:            ✓   |       |   *   |   *   |   **  |  ***  |   **
Hickory Ridge:             |       |  ***  |  ***  |       |   *   |   *
Mesquite:                  |   ✓   |   **  |       |   **  |  ***  |   *
Pinewood Hills:        ✓   |   ✓   |   *   |  ***  |   **  |   *   |   **
```

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Claim Overlook:        ✓   |       |  ***  |   **  |       |   *   |   **
Nugget Plateau:        ✓   |       |  ***  |  ***  |       |   *   |   **
Placer Vista:          ✓   |       |  ***  |  ***  |       |   *   |   **
Prospect:              ✓   |       |  ***  |   **  |       |   *   |   **
```

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Conestoga Crossing:    ✓   |   ✓   |   **  |   *   |   *   |  ***  |   *
Frontier Fields:       ✓   |       |   *   |       |  ***  |   **  |   *
Pioneer Plains:        ✓   |       |       |       |  ***  |  ***  |   *
Settler's Rest:        ✓   |   ✓   |   **  |   *   |   *   |  ***  |   *
```

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
                      Rail |  Sea  |  Coal |  Ore  |  Oil  | Water |  Wind
Mustang Run:           ✓   |       |  ***  |       |       |   *   |   **
Painted Point:         ✓   |       |   **  |   **  |       |   *   |   **
Palomino:              ✓   |       |   **  |  ***  |       |   *   |   **
Wrangler's Rest:       ✓   |       |  ***  |   **  |       |   *   |   **
```

Comment: Would you add a legend explaining what the numbers represent?

Comment: The higher the number the more abundant the resource, that is all it means.

Comment: Good call, added a legend and some notes on city clustering

Comment: Just switched it from numeric to *'s to be a bit clearer

Comment: Great compilation.